# Layout и фон - вечная проблема

Tags: c++, qt, layout

[image: Происходит вот это]

Я использую StyleSheet чтобы поставить фон для Виджета, но как только я пишу

```
setStyleSheet("QWidget{background-image:url(./room.jpg);background-size:contain}");
```

... , у меня появляется результат, как на картинке. Думаю, это происходит из-за Layout-а. Что делать, если не могу убрать Лайаут, но нужен и фон?

Answer (score 1):

Менеджер размещения тут ни при чём. Фон устанавливается для всех `QWidget`, а также их наследников, что соответственно и приводит к такой радующей глаз мозаике.

Необходимо конкретизировать цель, для которой фон должен быть установлен. Если речь о `QMainWindow`, то указываем именно этот класс:

```
setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-image:url(./room.jpg);}");
```

... , если диалог, то соответственно:

```
setStyleSheet("QDialog{background-image:url(./room.jpg);}");
```

Иногда однотипных виджетов может быть несколько, и тогда одним лишь указанием класса уже не обойтись. В этом случае можно дать имя объекту, а затем использовать это имя для целевого указания стиля. Например:

```
setStyleSheet(
    "QDialog#dlg1{" \
        "background-image:url(./room1.jpg);" \
    "}" \
    "QDialog#dlg2{" \
        "background-image:url(./room2.jpg);" \
    "}"
);

QDialog dlg1, dlg2;
dlg1.setObjectName("dlg1");
dlg2.setObjectName("dlg2");
```

Подробнее о правилах использования селекторов можно почитать [в справке Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html).

От себя хочется добавить, что лучше не вставлять стили непосредственно в cpp-файлы. Лучше завести какой-нибудь отдельный файл **my_style.qss**:

```
QWidget#my_wdg {
    color: silver;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Ну а где-нибудь в **main.cpp** осуществлять подгрузку и установку собственного стиля:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    {
        QFile file("my_style.qss");
        if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
            app.setStyleSheet(file.readAll());
    }

    QWidget wdg;
    wdg.setObjectName("my_wdg");
    wdg.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```